# Sending non-repeating emails from sheets with no finite row definition

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am successfully sending emails from sheets and it is populating a "sent" column and then not repeating the sending of emails once run again.

I would like to open this up so that the rows are not defined so that I can add emails to this document as the information comes in.

The email column would be populated over time and I would not like to edit the script each time as this is counterproductive.

Here is the sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1f6qUjGYHZtRRGCbyh5oNzM7o64B-wlkrTpB1ac64I2U/edit?usp=sharing

Because the code is set to a set range, it is not picking up beyond row 5.

If I change the range to L100, it serves up an error, presumably because there are no email addresses beyond row 5

```
var EMAIL_SENT = 'EMAIL_SENT';
function sendEmails2() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 4; 
  var numRows = 2; 
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("J4:L5");
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[0]; 
    var message = row[1]; 
    var emailSent = row[2]; 
    if (emailSent != EMAIL_SENT) { 
      var subject = 'Non-repeating emails sent from Sheets with no row limit 001';
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
      sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 12).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    }
  }
}
```

I'd like to be able to have an infinite number of rows and to be able to run the script repeatedly and for it to not send emails to addresses it has previously sent to but only to the newly added emails when I hit run the script

Comment: Welcome, please edit your question to identify the specific criteria that should trigger an email, and edit your spreadsheet to show an example of where an email should be sent. At present the "Mail_Sent" has no example values; and you don't address the issue of whether a "message" value should exist. Of course, no emaiul can be sent without an emails address, but you don't acknowledge this eier.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're close, you should use `getDataRange()` instead of a static range in your code. See below a version with a couple of edits:

```
var EMAIL_SENT = 'EMAIL_SENT';
function sendEmails2() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 4; 
  // var numRows = 2; --> not used
  var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange(); // Get the entire range having data
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i = startRow-1; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[0]; 
    var message = row[1]; 
    var emailSent = row[2]; 
    if (emailSent != EMAIL_SENT) { 
      var subject = 'Non-repeating emails sent from Sheets with no row limit 001';
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
      data[i][2] = EMAIL_SENT;
    }
  }
  dataRange.setValues(data); // More efficient to only write once
}
```